# Android Can't save to an array

Tags: android, arrays

I have global array. When i want to save something in some method and after that show it from that array it has error NullPointerException. Array is Object type. Code is like this

```
class Something {
   public CoordinatesObject[] coordinates;

   Something() {
      coordinates = new CoordinatesObject[4];
   }

   public String myMethod() {
      if (coordinates.length==0){
      coordinates[0] = new CoordinatesObject(0,0);
      }
   }
   return Integer.toString(coordinates[0].getX());
}
```

What's wrong?

Sorry I have updated the code. I've created a new array in constructor

Answer (score 1):

You created an array with this line:

```
coordinates = new CoordinatesObject[4];
```

and then you're trying to create CoordinatesObject like that:

```
if (coordinates.length==0){
     coordinates[0] = new CoordinatesObject(0,0);
}
```

but coordinates.length is going to be equal to 4 which means an object of CoordinatesObject class won't be created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually allocate space for the array, right now you just have a reference to nothing.

Also note that arrays are fixed-length, you may want to consider using a collection (like a list) instead, depending on your needs.

Comment: I have updated the code I inicialize the array in constructor

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Array with new as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have a NULL reference. As the previous poster points out, you need to define and create some space for your array.

Comment: Upvoting Rafal Roszak's answer as it is clear and explains your issue.